# Best Practice for href CSRF Prevention?

Tags: csrf

I am writing a basic message board plugin for my site. Moderators will have href links on each post to delete, unapprove, edit etc. What is the best way to prevent a CSRF attack on these links? The only thing I could come up with is to make a form for each link with a hidden token and have the href submit the form using javascript, but this seems like an extremely unwieldy solution. Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [OWASP CSRF Prevention cheatsheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)?

Comment: I've read something similar. Would be including a token as a GET parameter be sufficient under these circumstances since I'm not dealing with a credit card number or anything sensitive like that?

Comment: @Slipflurry - So long as the token is unique and unguessable and can be correlated to the user, sure.

Comment: @Oded - From the OWASP document that you linked, **Disclosure of Token in URL**: "_CSRF tokens in GET requests are potentially leaked at several locations: browser history, HTTP log files, network appliances that make a point to log the first line of an HTTP request, and Referer headers if the protected site links to an external site._" Don't put CSRF tokens in GET requests unless you don't care if they are compromised. And then why bother having tokens at all?

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat a CSRF token to the href link.

And check that token on the moderators session,

The whole point of XSRF is to make requests, response dependent. So simply concat the token to the response.

Comment: Well what I meant e.g : <a href='remove?id=10&token=1234'> </a>

Comment: GET requests should not change the state of the server